# Webservice-request with array

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap

I've got a webservice which takes a RequestDTO with 6 strings in it. When testing the webservice I simply send an XML like this and it works just fine:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"   
xmlns:java="java:dk.thg.fll" 
xmlns:java1="java:dk.thg.common">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
  <web:service>
     <web:request>
        <java:request>
           <java1:Id>1</java1:Id>
           <java1:User>anton</java1:User>
        </java:request>
        <java:ms>4453</java:ms>
        <java:element>GG</java:element>
        <java:service>L</java:service>
        <java:data><![CDATA[ <data><task><type>T</type><action>A</action> </task></data> ]]></java:data>
     </web:request>
  </web:service>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

My problem now is that I have to create a webservice which can process a set of requests. My idea is to simply have an array of RequestDTO. This means that the new webservice takes a MultiRequestDTO which contains an array of RequestDTO's.

But how should the XML look like? - When I test with SoapUI it autogenerates the request xml and this is what it says my new webservice XML looks like:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:java="java:dk.thg.fll" 
xmlns:java1="java:dk.thg.common">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
  <web:service>
     <web:multiRequest>
        <java:request>
           <java1:Id>?</java1:Id>
           <java1:User>?</java1:User>
        </java:request>
        <java:requests/>
     </web:multiRequest>
  </web:service>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

How should the  (which is my array) look like when sending the request?

I've tried to simply copy the contents from the first XML (copied the tag ), but no luck..

Anyone able to help out?

* EDIT *** - Request

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:java="java:dk.thg.fll" xmlns:java1="java:dk.thg.common">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
  <web:service>
     <web:multiRequest>
        <java:requestInfo>
           <java1:Id>10</java1:Id>
           <java1:User>1234</java1:User>
        </java:requestInfo>
        <java:requests>
        singleRequest
                <java:request>
                    <java1:Id>10</java1:Id>
                    <java1:User>789</java1:User>
                </java:request>
                <java:msisdn>4561814453</java:msisdn>
                <java:element>4453</java:element>
                <java:service>GG</java:service>
                <java:details><![CDATA[ <details><task><type>T</type><action>A</action> </task></details>]]></java:details>
    </java1:singleRequest>
    </java:requests>
     </web:multiRequest>
  </web:service>
```

This is what I send out now.. but all the values inside  arent recieved and the object in the array just contains null values.

Comment: In your XML which element is array type?

Comment: java:requests is of type array

Comment: Are using any XSD or the elements are declared in wsdl?And for your java:request is maxOccurs="unbounded" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"  xmlns:java="java:dk.thg.fll"  xmlns:java1="java:dk.thg.common"> 
<soapenv:Header/>
 <soapenv:Body> 
  <web:service>  
    <web:multiRequest>  
       <java:request>   
         <java1:Id>?</java1:Id>   
         <java1:User>?</java1:User>  
       </java:request>   
   <java:request>   
         <java1:Id>?</java1:Id>   
         <java1:User>?</java1:User>  
       </java:request>     
  <java:requests/>  
  <java:request>   
         <java1:Id>?</java1:Id>   
         <java1:User>?</java1:User>  
       </java:request>   
  </web:multiRequest> 
  </web:service> </soapenv:Body> 
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Your XML request suppose to look like this if you want to trigger more than one java:request

Comment: You can add multiple java:request and trigger it on SOAPUI

Comment: I get the following error message:    

Caused by: com.bea.xml.XmlException: required soap array type not present

Comment: Ya that was question your java:request is having maxOccurs="unbounded"?  Can you Share your WSDL?

Comment: Hi.. yes the java:requests has maxOccurs="unbounded"

Comment: Ok what i think your web:multirequest should take array type of java:request so the maxOccurs="unbounded" will be applicable to web:multirequest not with java:request.

Comment: Hi again.. I got past that issue, but now I have another problem.. 

I recieve the array fine now, but all the values of the objects in the array are received as null. I'll update the original post with the new response XML

Comment: Hi again. I got it solved and will accept your answer.. it helped me in the right direction so thank you :) I was simply my request XML that was bad and your very first comment was spot on :)